# How to find the type of GPU on my laptop

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, lenovo-laptop

I am encountering an annoying though not significant problem. I tried to find the GPU type of my laptop,
it is win8.1, Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 11S.

According to the tutorial online, I opened the device manager, but in the list display adaptor , it only vaguely says " HD graphics family".

I also tried to use advanced restart to get into UEFI BIOS mode, but in the firmware setting->system info, there is simply nothing about GPU!

the reason why I want to find the GPU is the specs listed on Lenovo website says the GPU is HD 4000 while I remember it listed as HD 4200 on my local future shop store, so I just want to make sure I was not fooled!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to find all the information for your gpu.
Other wise right-click on your desktop and open `screen resolution` click advanced settings, you can see your gpu there also.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Device Manager, and select the Display Adapter again.

in Properties of the `HD graphics family`, go to `Details` and choose `Hardware IDs` from the dropdown.  You should see something like:

```
PCI/VEN_xxxx&DEV_yyyy&......
```

The `xxxx` and `yyyy` hexadecimal numbers for the unique IDs for the GPU pci card.

Search for those two numbers in Google, and it should lead you to PCI database that will tell you what card it is.